# Implementing Prestashop Multisite in subdomain

Tags: prestashop

I want to create multiple Prestashop installation for each client in a subdomain for example (client1store.example.com, client2store.example.com etc) using the same root installation (without duplicating the installation files for each client directory) also separated data (not sharing same products etc), is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, read here [former Prestashop Official documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/The+multistore+interface)

Comment: But they share the same data?

Comment: You can choose what data to share, it is all described there.